# boot loop, loading initial ramdisk

Tags: boot

Woke up to my PC in a boot loop. I tried deleting 'quiet' but the text goes by so fast that my camera won't capture it. Tried searching for how to make it stop before it fails but did not find anything. Pause break/scroll lock does not work.

Previous kernel does the same.

I have Ubuntu on main drive and debian on a different drive. Debian fails in the same way. Debian has its own boot sector on the other drive. With Debian I don't even see it give any text if I delete 'quiet'. I removed my dedicated gpu and went to iGPU, doesn't help. Secureboot on/off does not change anything. I tried my ram sticks one by one and tried a spare I had laying around, same behavior. I do not have access to a live USB or another PC. If I could see where it fails then maybe I could start solving the problem.

Both Ubuntu and Debian are encrypted.

Comment: BIOS is fully updated.

Comment: I think your best best is to try and `chroot` into the system and check its logs. Unfortunately, you'll have to use a LiveUSB for that :/

Comment: I got a live USB, that will not boot either. Changed CMOS battery, have had boot problems with windows because of that. Didn't work. Guess I'll have to buy a new computer. I will be very disappointed if windows manages to boot on this machine.